# Is there ready to use Dictionary Preference like Personal Dictionary in Android Settings

Tags: android, dictionary, android-fragments, android-preferences

I try to implement Dictionary Preference like "Personal Dictionary" in Android Settings (the images are attached).

Unfortunately, I was not able to find such ready to use component or a tutorial about ordinary Preference (not DialogPreference) extending.

So I planned to extend Preference and show DictionaryEditorFragment in Preference#onClick event. But it is unclear how to do that. It looks as FragmentManager is not accessible from Preference.

Please, could you direct me to an existing component if such exists or to a tutorial or propose concept of a solution?

At the moment I have only idea to create DictionaryEditor like View and not Fragment.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have not found ready to use component so I had to create simple dictionary based on DialogPreference.

[image]